# Generating Account Statement as PDF

Tags: visualforce, account, pdf

I need to generate a document for any given account that lists a detailed view of their contacts, opportunities, activity etc. My first instinct is to simply use renderAs on a custom visualforce page that contains all the account info I need. However, I'm realizing that I would need to generate such a page for each opportunity connected to the account (and possibly each contact though I might get by with a related list there). Is there a way to generate a page for each item that would appear in a related list so we could see (for example) the description of an opportunity that would be too long for a related list column?

Secondarily, if they do end up being separate pages, how would you recommend turning them into a single document with as little effort on the part of the user as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to use a combination of pages and components. Each top-level page uses renderAs to make the PDF files, but uses components so you can have the same look-and-feel across the various types. For example, you might declare three components: pdfAccount, pdfContact, and pdfOpportunity. Then, depending on the page, you'll simply render the pages as you like.

## AccountPDF

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" renderAs="PDF">
    <c:pdfAccount account="{!Account}" />
    <apex:repeat var="accountContact" value="{!Account.Contacts}">
        <c:pdfContact contact="{!accountContact}" />
    </apex:repeat>
    <!-- and opportunity code here... -->
</apex:page>
```

As far as making it easy for the user: just create a Custom Button or Link, using the Visualforce pages you just created. The user clicks it, and the PDF will be generated for them to view or print.

Also, if each *record* should be its own page, just set up a div with the page-break-before attribute in each component:

```
<apex:component>
    <div style="page-break-before: always"></div>
    <!-- rest of code here -->
```